# Amazon SimpleDB cache problem

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'm experimenting with Amazon SimpleDB (using [Rick Helms' PHP API](http://webmasterinresidence.ca/simpledb/index.php)) and I've noticed that the updates are not in real time. I mean, if in the same page I contact the service to delete and item and the retrieve the items list, the deleted item is *often* still there.

Any idea on what's going on and how to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: Probably a transaction problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generally the case with large scale databases, they have eventual consistency, meaning that information does not immediately nor atomically propagate to all the nodes.

You can have a look to this: http://www.satine.org/archives/2007/12/13/amazon-simpledb/

The official page also notes that it is eventually consistent giving an explanation here:
http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/#eventually-consistent

Apparently, you can force consistent reads as explained here:
http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/#consistent